# Get user profile picture - whatsapp smooch

Tags: webhooks, chatbot, whatsapp, profile, smooch

I use `smooch` to connect a bot to whatsapp.

My webhook is configured with `includeClient` - to get user information.

I am wondering if it is possible to get the user profile picture in smooch with the whatsapp business api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently possible - User profile pictures are not shared with businesses using the WhatsApp the Business APIs.